# Repeated clicks on Cordova Googlemaps plugin

Tags: android, angular, cordova, google-maps, ionic-framework

I have a very simple test map for the Cordova Google maps plugin (using version @ionic-native/google-maps@3.10.3). I'm just trying to get a feel for it before using it. I have a click event handler in there but it only handles the first click. After that, it stops responding to any future clicks. Here is the code for the map onready:

```
map.one(GoogleMapsEvent.MAP_READY).then(() => {

  map.one(GoogleMapsEvent.MAP_LONG_CLICK).then((latLng) => {
    console.log("long click: ", latLng);
  }); 

});
```

Also, why is it map.one instead of map.on?

Here is my ionic info:

```
Cordova CLI: 6.5.0
Ionic Framework Version: 3.3.0
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.3
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.3.
ios-deploy version: Not install
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Windows 10
Node Version: v6.10.0
Xcode version: Not installed
```

Comment: change map.one() to map.on()?

Comment: @getbuckts This throws an error: "Property 'then' does not exist on type 'Observable<any>'

My first thought was that .one meant to do it once and so I changed it to on and got that error. That's why I asked why it had to be one instead of on. All the docs show 'one' and it is really weird.

Answer (score 0):

Check docs again: https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps-doc/blob/master/v1.4.0/class/Map/README.md.  Its asking for you to pass in call back function when the event is fired.  There is no Promise return which is how your code is.

```
var evtName = plugin.google.maps.event.MAP_LONG_CLICK;
map.on(evtName, function(latLng) {
   alert("Map was long clicked.\n" +
     latLng.toUrlValue());
});
```

Comment: Okay, so plugin throws an error: "Cannot find name 'plugin'". I have to use the GoogleMapsEvent import from @ionic-native/google-maps
evtName = GoogleMapsEvent.MAP_LONG_CLICK for it to work.

Next up
map.on(evtName, callback() {});
gives: "Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target" meaning that map.on (i also tried map.one) doesn't take two parameters.

If it helps, I have @ionic-native/google-maps@3.10.3 not 1.4.0.